# What is the simplest, poor performance hash class for standard library containers?

Tags: c++, hash, std

In situations where performance can be ignored, some standard library containers still require a custom hash class for most of the types. Assume I have a type `SomeType` defined somewhere, I want to use `std::unordered_set` and I don't care about performance. The minimum I have to write is something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Hash42 {
  size_t operator()(T const& e) {return 42;}
};

std::unordered_set<SomeType, Hash42<SomeType>> s;
```

Is there a shorter version? Is there a universal hash class defined somewhere?

Comment: No, this is not enough. You also need to implement equality comparison for your class.

Comment: If you're willing to use unordered_set with a hash function that returns a constant, why not just use a vector instead?

Comment: @jtbandes `unordered_set` makes it convenient to eliminate repetitions for not sortable types.

Comment: In situations where performance can be ignored you should not use hash_map/hash_set, just use other containers.

Comment: That might sound good, but the performance is going to be terrible.  I know you don't care about it, but you should at least a little bit.  With a constant hash all elements will be in the same bucket and the standard basically mandates that a bucket is a linked list which is basically the worst container, only surpassed by forward list.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In general case, yes. Large category of types, i.e. classes with all members being equality comparable, do not require that, though.

Comment: @NathanOliver *performance is going to be terrible* how do you know? I measured the performance and it is just fine for my needs.

Comment: You have no choice. unordered_set requires equality comparison. Feel free to see how far you can get without it.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Because a linked list basically means you have a cache miss every time you try to access the element.  Worst case, you'll have O(N) misses so you'll basically be running at memory speed, which is orders of magnitude slower than it could be using a vector.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You are right. I didn't get very far with my wrong assumption. :-(

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a shorter version?

You can make the operator itself a template instead of the class, thereby allowing the type argument to be deduced:

```
struct Hash0 {
  std::size_t operator()(auto const& e) {return 0;}
};

std::unordered_set<SomeType, Hash0> s;
```

> Is there a universal hash class defined somewhere?

Now there is. There isn't one in the standard library.

---

Of course, one should use this only if their goal is to make the program slow.